# bootstrap3 navbar toggle button not dropping menu when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not able to get the navbar button to toggle the menu down when the navbar is collapsed for smaller browsers.  I have tried all the suggestions on this forum regarding different js links and I have looked at the source code of numerous bootstrap example sites where the button works but I am still not able to get this to work.  I can even build it in bootply where it works fine and when I bring it into my file directory it doesn't work.

Is there something in this code that is obviously preventing this from working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Snow's Farm</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-     scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content>
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="./bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>

<body class="bs-docs-home" style data-twttr-rendered="true">
    <a class="sr-only" href="#content">Skip navigation</a>

    <!-- Docs master nav -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Snow's Farm</a>
</div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="dropdown" href="www.google.com"><p>The Farm Family</p></a></li>     
        <li><a href="www.yahoo.com"><p>Mulch</p></a></li>  
        <li><a href="#soil"><p>Soil</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#stone"><p>Stone</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#trees"><p>Christmas Trees</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#delivery"><p>Delivery</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#docs"><p>Pricing Documents</p></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

</body>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<!-- JavaScript plugins (requires jQuery) -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="./bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Enable responsive features in IE8 with Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) -->
<script src="./respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the example, or a fiddle of it? From glancing at your code, it seems like it should work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wv5MS/ Seems to work like a charm... Btw, any particular reason you are loading jquery.js twice? Maybe its that local version of jquery that is screwing your code

Comment: i was trying one version against the other, i usually comment one of the two out, i am only using local one now.[link](http://testingtechs.com)

Comment: It looks like no `.js` files are being loaded in your website. That should explain quite a lot :) Now why? I have no clue...

Comment: `type="test/javascript"` that could be a reason... Fix that and see if it works...

Comment: ok so i made those changes, when i check my browser tools it shows all js files as loading, still no drop down functionality

Comment: ok so there was a problem with the local jquery and it also needs to be called before the bootstrap.js is called or else there will be an error thrown.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap uses jquery, so you need to call it first, or your browser wont know what it is reading :) i see its working now